# File Upload (restrict to Camera / not Gallery)

Tags: html, file-upload, image-uploading

I´d like to Upload Fotos on my Website, but want to restrict it only for the camera, not the gallery.

Reason: I want to use the uploadtime as a timestamp and it should not do that with photos from the galery. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `<input type="file" id="take-picture" accept="image/*"capture="camera">` i don't get your second point..? can you rephrase it

Comment: thanks, that did the trick. There was no second point, just an explanation why I want to use it.

I want to make sure that only pictures from the camera right know can be uploaded, for legal reasons.